# StackOverflow on Lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, stack-overflow, java-stream

I have the following lambda expression:

```
public static ArrayList<Sample> getSamplesWithFeatureValueGT(List<Sample> samples, FeatureLabel feature, int value) {

    return samples.stream().filter(x -> x.features.get(feature).compareTo(new BigDecimal(Double.toString(value))) > 0).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));

}
```

Where each `Sample` object contains a `HashMap<FeatureLabel, BigDecimal> feature` field and `FeatureLabel` is a enum.

I am trying to filter a collections of samples and obtain only those which have a certain FeatureLabel value less than a certain amount.

I am testing with a List containing 297 sample objects, and am getting a StackOverflow error as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapSink(AbstractPipeline.java:548)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at uk.ac.dariosdesk.simpledecisiontree.TreeUtils.getSamplesWithFeatureValueGT(TreeUtils.java:72)
    at uk.ac.dariosdesk.simpledecisiontree.ContinuousFeature.CalculateEntropySplittingOnFeature(ContinuousFeature.java:46)
    at uk.ac.dariosdesk.simpledecisiontree.ContinuousFeature.lambda$CalculateCutOffPoint$0(ContinuousFeature.java:38)
    at uk.ac.dariosdesk.simpledecisiontree.ContinuousFeature$$Lambda$9/1848402763.compare(Unknown Source)
```

Then at ContinuousFeature.java:46 I have:

```
 List<Sample> samplesGreaterThanCutOff = TreeUtils.getSamplesWithFeatureValueGT(samples, super.featureName, cutOffPoint);
```

Which is part of a function called at line 38:

```
cutOffPoint = IntStream.range(minValue.intValue(), maxValue.intValue())
                .boxed()
                .min((o1, o2) -> Double.compare(CalculateEntropySplittingOnFeature(samples, o1), CalculateEntropySplittingOnFeature(samples, o2))).get();
    }
```

Essentially, line CalculateEntropySplittingOnFeature calls my getSamplesWithFeatureValueGT (and it's equivalent LT for less than) several times to filter the list of samples based on feature properties.

Any advice?

Comment: A StackOverflow indicates a recursion problem, but there is no recursion here. I think it just happened to be thrown there because the stack is exhausted there, but the bug is elsewhere. Examine the whole stack trace (or post it), and look for a repetitive pattern of recursive method calls. The fact that it happens in TreeUtils is also a strong indication that you're probably using a faulty recursive algorithm or data structure (like a tree node having itself as parent).

Comment: Seems that the supplied code cannot be the source of StackOverflowError. Could you provide more context? Also you should not compare the result of `compareTo` with exact non-zero values. It's not specified that result is -1 when number is less. It can be any number less than zero. Seems that it would be more efficient to write `BigDecimal val = BigDecimal.valueOf(value); return samples.stream().filter(x -> x.features.get(feature).compareTo(val) <= 0).collect(..)`.

Comment: Also consider using `EnumMap` instead of `HashMap` when your key type is enum.

Comment: You posted the code of `getSamplesWithFeatureValueLT` but the stack-trace mentions `getSamplesWithFeatureValueGT` (or is that a typo?)

Comment: Thanks for all your comments, I've included more details and fixed my BigDecimal to check for > 0 / < 0 instead of == -1 or == 1

Comment: Is provided stacktrace complete or you omitted some of stack frames? Please post the complete stack trace.

Comment: I'd look into 1)  `features` inside the Sample (is it a Map?) 2) what is inside that features container is it `BigDecimal`, or something else for which you have you overloaded the `compareTo()` method?